# non editable R code and make it grey mode

Tags: r

I need to give my R code to my colleague, who does not know R

He just need to execute it

How to make the R code non editable, so as to avoid pain of debugging resulting accidental change in code

Comment: Tell him to run it from the command line, so he doesn't even have to open the file.

Comment: For what reason does he need to execute it? Is it possible to simply make an Rmarkdown and send him the html file that you create? Or does he have to provide his own input file somehow?

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you give someone code, you can expect that they'll be able to modify it. That's the whole point of source code.

If you wanted to offer some protection against *unintended* tampering of code, you could do a couple of things, such as

- When distributing the source, distribute a digest with it, and hope that the end user will act in good faith to verify the source against the digest
- On the end user's filesystem, make the file read-only; this is only a "suggestion" and is easily overcome by the end user

In general, if you want someone to "just execute" something without modifying the source, you don't give them the source; instead, you compile it (with an obfuscator) and give them the binary, and hope that they aren't a skilled reverse engineer. There are indeed compilers for R, though I don't know of any obfuscators.

Comment: If it is a Windows system, you could also make it read only inside a zip archive and then send it to them. Not sure if other systems respect those permissions when extracting. Easily overcome as you say, but it will stop someone who isn't savvy with computers.

Comment: @thelatemail Half of the time, that won't even stop someone, because many editors will only show a warning rather than an error when writing to read-only files. So that's not really an acceptable solution. The proper thing to do here is compilation.

Comment: Well, I know that, but you did suggest it as an option. I was just adding that you don't have to have access to their file-system to make something read only.

Comment: @thelatemail Fair point - thank you.